# cakephp 1.3.11 plugin routing not working

Tags: cakephp

I'm building a blog plugin for CakePHP. It is called 'blog'.

I am following the manual on plugin routing but my links won't work.  http://book.cakephp.org/view/951/Plugin-routing

For example, when I am on this page: appname/blog/posts/index, I have a link to the index action of the users plugin. So I built my link as follows:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    __('List Users', true), 
    array(
        'plugin' => 'users', 
        'controller' => 'users', 
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
```

But the link keep pointing to app/blog/users/index instead of app/users/users/index. Why is that?

PS: users is also a plugin (from CakeDC).

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

you can set routes like this:

```
   Router::connect('/users', array('admin' => false, 'plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'tests', 'action' => 'test') );
```

'admin' is for admin routing and 'plugin' for plugin url.